# android @Suppress errors vs @TargetApi

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, suppress-warnings

Sometimes I case out code for certain versions of Android that may run my application. Eclipse with the latest Android tools still notices that my Manifest document allows lower versions of Android and therefore decides my code has errors in it.

A solution to this is to add a `@Suppress` tag above the method so it doesn't report the error, or another suggestion is to add a `@TargetApi` tag above the function

I dont understand the differences, or the consequences

Comment: I think that CommonsWare has answered this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14341042/what-is-better-suppresslint-or-targetapi) hope it helps...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`@TargetApi(NN)` says "Hey, Android! Yes, I know I am using something newer than what is allowed for in my `android:minSdkVersion`. That's OK, though, 'cause I am sure that I am using `Build` (or something) such that the newer code only runs on newer devices. Please pretend that my `minSdkVersion` is `NN` for the purposes of this (class|method)".

`@SuppressLint`, to address the same error, says "Hey, Android! Yes, I know I am using something newer than what is allowed for in my `android:minSdkVersion`. Quit complaining.".

Hence, given a choice of `@TargetApi(NN)` or `@SuppressLint`, go with `@TargetApi(NN)`. There, if you start using something newer than `NN` -- and therefore your existing version-checking logic may be insufficient -- you will get yelled at again.