# Android make higher level API call without targeting a high level SDK

Tags: android, api, reflection, target

I need to dim the navigation bar in my app targeting API 10. I cannot target 14, capable of that, because my app starts behaving too slow after that single change. Is there another way to do that? i.e. reflection, or using an external helper app as a service, Or maybe something else?

Comment: "because my app starts behaving too slow after that single change" -- perhaps you should use Traceview and determine what the problem is. Changing build target (i.e., `compileSdkVersion`) should have zero impact on performance. Changing `targetSdkVersion` could have an impact on performance, but you will not be able to keep an artificially low `targetSdkVersion` forever. The `compileSdkVersion` dictates what classes/methods you can reference in your app.

Comment: Have you looked into @TargetAPI? Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24798481/android-target-api)