# Picasso sometimes not download photos and crash my application

Tags: android, picasso, airplane-mode

```
Picasso.with(getActivity().getApplicationContext()).load(imageString).resize(250, 250)
    .into(image, new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            Log.e("profilepicsucess", "");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError() {
            Log.e("profilepicfalse :3", "");
        }
});
```

When I try to download photo using Picasso, SOMETIMES my application crashed **WITHOUT** accessing onSuccess, onError Functions! and I have this in my logcat

> (W/Settings﹕ Setting airplane_mode_on has moved from android.provider.Settings.System to android.provider.Settings.Global, returning read-only value.)

I searched for it I found that I should import :

```
import static android.provider.Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON;
```

and write this function

```
static boolean isAirplaneModeOn(Context context) {
    ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
    return Settings.System.getInt(contentResolver, AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, 0) != 0;
}
```

Actually I don't know WHERE to write it**

Comment: "crashed WITHOUT accessing onSuccess, onError Functions! and I have this in my logcat " -- if you are crashing, there will be a Java stack trace associated with that crash. The warning that you cite is not part of a Java stack trace. Focus on the Java stack trace, to determine where and why you are crashing.

Comment: do you think that picasso not the reason for crashing ??

Comment: Can you post your logcat, so that we can assist further `:)`

Comment: The 'airplane mode' warning has nothing to do with the crash. I see it also when picasso works correctly. It's just something that got moved in latest Android versions and Picasso it not yet updated for that. But I'm pretty sure it has nothing to do with your crashes. As CommonsWare said, there should be some stack trace in LogCat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are getting the warning is because from Jelly Bean 4.2 and up, the airplane mode settings have moved to `Settings.Global`.

Use this function to check the airplane mode:

```
/**
 * Gets the state of Airplane Mode.
 * 
 * @param context
 * @return true if enabled.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
public static boolean isAirplaneModeOn(Context context) {        
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
        return Settings.System.getInt(context.getContentResolver(), 
                Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, 0) != 0;          
    } else {
        return Settings.Global.getInt(context.getContentResolver(), 
                Settings.Global.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, 0) != 0;
    }       
}
```

However, I would need more detail to assist with the crashes.

This is how to use this function:

```
if(!isAirplaneModeOn(getActivity().getApplicationContext()){   
    //Picasso Code
    Picasso.with(getActivity().getApplicationContext()).load(imageString).resize(250, 250)
        .into(image, new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                Log.e("profilepicsucess", "");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError() {
                Log.e("profilepicfalse :3", "");
            }
    });
}else{
    //do something else?
}
```

Comment: where can I set this function ??

Comment: @AyaRadwan I presume you mean how do you call it?

Comment: Actually I don't how can I use it

Comment: would you please explain to me how can I use with full example, please:)

Comment: what does this mean ? @TargetApi

Comment: I tells your developer environment that this code block is targeting a specific version of Android which can prevent code unwanted warnings from being shown in your developer environment. I believe @CommonsWare would link to their post here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17665816/566127

Comment: would you please check my other question :)) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30834996/my-connection-code-sometimes-not-working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81126/discussion-between-aya-radwan-and-david-passmore).